# Using lambda conditional and pandas str.contains to lump strings

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, kaggle

Trying to learn some stuff, I'm messing around with the global shark attack database on Kaggle and I'm trying to find the best way to lump strings using a `lambda` function and `str.contains`.

Basically anywhere a string contains a phrase with `skin diving` e.g. `'skin diving for abalone'` , in the `data['Activity']` column I want to replace the activity with `skin diving`. (there are 92 variations for skin diving hence trying to use the lambda function)

I can return a boolean series using

```
data['Activity].str.contains('skin diving')
```

But I'm unsure how to change the value if this condition is true

My lambda function = `data.apply(lambda x: 'free diving' if x.str.contains('free diving))` but i'm getting a syntax error and i'm not familiar enough with lambda functions and pandas to get it right, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `if` expression must have an `else` part: `x if condition else y`. Your lambda does not have the `else` part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of using a Series.str method, you can use the **in** operator in your lambda to test for the substring

```
data['activity'] = data['activity'].apply(lambda x: 'skin diving' if 'skin diving' in x else x)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, very useful. I hadn't thought about the `in` operator

Comment: How would I use regex against a string? I want to loop through series cells and if cell contains parenthesis `(` or `)` do something, else do something else

Comment: It also seems to be the case that a conditional in a `lambda` statement requires an `else` clause.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `str.contains` method with `np.where`

```
In [141]: df
Out[141]:
         activity
0  free diving ok
1              ok

In [142]: df.activity = np.where(df.activity.str.contains('free diving'),
                                 'free diving', df.activity)

In [143]: df
Out[143]:
      activity
0  free diving
1           ok
```